# Append Entry To KeystoreFile

Tags: security, keystore

I have an keystore file with AES 256 keys and I would like to increase it. I have the following code:

```
final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE_TYPE);
ks.load(inputStream, ksPassword);
ks.setEntry(entryName, new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(appKey), entryPassword);
ks.store(new FileOutputStream(outputStream, true));
```

But when I call the store method the new key entry isn't stored on a existing file referenced by my outputStream. Any ideas? Is possible to increment keys on existing keystore file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!
When I created the outputStream I created using the StandardOpenOption.APPEND. I changed to StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING and that works!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no concept of increasing Key Size on an existing Key. If you want a Key of different size,  you have to create a different Key.
2. When you are storing a new Key, you might be referring to a different File in your outputstream, that might be the reason it isn't being added to your existing KeyStore.

Comment: My output stream reffers to the same file that was be loaded in inputStream

Comment: If the `entryName` is the same it must be overriding the existing key. Try giving a different alias name.